# Unable to get response of HTTP call in Postman

Tags: java, api, http

I am receiving a HTTP call on socket in java. I am sending small data in HTTP from postman and able to receive it in my java application, but the response sent by Java is not received in Postman.

Here is my Java end code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;




public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ServerSocket scket;
        Socket clientSocket;
        byte inFromInde[] = new byte[1000];
        int read_size_inde = 0;


        try{
            scket = new ServerSocket(7502);
            scket.setReuseAddress(true);
            clientSocket = scket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted");

            BufferedInputStream inputFromInde = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            read_size_inde = inputFromInde.read(inFromInde,0,1000);
            String str = new String(inFromInde);
            System.out.println(str);
            BufferedOutputStream outputToInde = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();


           String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
           response = response = "Date: Fri, 04 May 2001 20:08:11 GMT\r\n";
           response = response + "Server: Sanjits Server\r\n";
           response = response + "Connection: close\r\n";
           response = "Hi Hope you are doing good";
           byte[] bytes = response.getBytes();
           output.write(bytes);
           output.flush();
           output.close();
           scket.close();
           clientSocket.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Exception is bind Failed");

        }
    }

}
```

[Console output in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJTO1.png)

[Postman side image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUZOj.png)

How can I get response in Postman.

Comment: It appears you have a typo that is obliterating your HTTP response line: `response = response = "Date: …";`  Notice the presence of two `=` assignment operators.  (And then you obliterate the response line and all of the headers when your program executes `response = "Hi Hope you are doing good";`.)  Also, there must be *two* `\r\n` sequences between the headers and the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things to correct.

First you are overwriting your response string with

```
response = response = "Date: Fri, 04 May 2001 20:08:11 GMT\r\n";
....
response = "Hi Hope you are doing good";
```

Your probably want to concatenate your strings like

```
response = response + "text";
```

or

```
response += "text";
```

or with the concat method

```
response = response.concat("text");
```

Your other problem regards your response format.
According to the HTTP specs header and body in a response should be separated by a CRLF (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6).

In order to be compliant you have to terminate the header part with a CRLF, so you have to add *an extra* \r\n (as VGR said).

So your response building should look something like this

```
String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
    .concat("Date: Fri, 04 May 2001 20:08:11 GMT\r\n")
    .concat("Server: Sanjits Server\r\n")
    .concat("Connection: close\r\n")
    .concat("\r\n") //additional CRLF!
    .concat("Hi Hope you are doing good");
```

Comment: Could just be postman, but when using the concat function, I would get a socket hangup error (meaning the response took too long). It worked fine when I used response += instead though

Comment: @mcdowellalex did you assign the result of .concat() to a variable? Concat does not change the string but returns a new concatenated string.

Comment: ohhhh no I didn't. In that case I should have just gotten back whatever I assigned the response string was right? `response = "some string"; response.concat("some more");` should just return "some string"?

Comment: @mcdowellalex That would return "some string", yes. This is because Strings are immutable in Java. But your postman probably did not "receive" the response because it was not formatted correctly or missing some info.